# Android theme doesn't work with Stripe CardMultilineWidget - react-native-android bridge

Tags: android, stripe-payments, themes, react-native

I'm new to mobile development and Android. I'm working on a react native app and trying to integrate the CardMultilineWidget from Stripe android (through react native bridge). The CardMultilineWidget is working fine, I can send and receive events to and from android to react native JS. But the only problem is I couldn't customize the styling of the widget in the native code.

I've tried this. I'm reading the resource file using a XML parser and passing it to the constructor of the CardMultilineWidget to build the widget using those attributes. The other attributes (like shouldShowPostalCode) seem to work fine but not the theme.

```
   XmlPullParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.cardinputattributes);
    try {
        parser.next();
        parser.nextTag();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    reactContext = context;
    AttributeSet attr = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
    cardMultilineWidget = new CardMultilineWidget(context,attr);
```

I'm loading the xml resource file and creating the widget using the attribute set. But for some reason, the theme in the resource file isn't taking effect.
Here are the resource files
[XML Resource file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLLk0.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.stripe.android.view.CardMultilineWidget android:id="@+id/cardMultiLineWidget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:theme="@style/CreditCardTheme"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/next_action_string"
    app:shouldShowPostalCode="false"
    android:padding="5dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" />
```

This is the file with the Theme - [Themes XML resource file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvJ2a.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
<style name="CreditCardTheme" parent="StripeBaseTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/lightYellow</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textPrimary</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/title</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/lightYellow</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/textPrimary</item>
    <item name="editTextColor">@color/textPrimary</item>
</style>
    </resources>
```

No matter what theme or style I give to the android:theme property, it didn't work.
Here is the UI from the app.
[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeEET.png)

I want to be able to customize the styling, like different highlight colors, text colors etc. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Edit: Passing the theme as an attribute doesn't seem to work. I used a layout file with the given cardmultilinewidget, and inflated it programmatically using LayoutInflater, and it worked. Thanks to @wsw for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you try to use the `CreditCardTheme` in the hosting activity instead of the `CardMultilineWidget`?

Comment: Hey @wsw, thank you for the comment! The CardMultilineWidget is the class provided by the Stripe. Not sure what you meant by using the CreditCardTheme

Comment: you've defined a custom theme called `CreditCardTheme ` which you are using it in `CardMultilineWidget android:theme` now. 
What I meant is that you should use that theme in the Activity which hosts the `CardMultilienWidget` if that make sense

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I tried what you said, but since I'm using react native I cannot modify the activity. So I added a layout file with the cardmultilinewidget and applied the theme to the layout and it worked. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: @Anorak could you post the solution below? So other developers with same problem (like me) can enjoy :)